# How can i plot a linear mixed model

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, data-visualization, random-effects-model

i have constructed a mixed model for a nested design. i have attached it below:

A researcher observes variation in wing size in a beetle species in South-America and wants to know whether wing size is associated to altitude. He therefore collects and measures beetles along an altitudinal gradient on several mountains (at 6 different altitudes: 150m, 300m, 450m, 600m, 750m and 900m). At each altitude he samples 2 patches and collects 6 beetles in each patch. In total he samples 3 such mountains, thus 216 individuals in total. In addition, he determines the sex (male vs female) of each beetle. Finally, he repeats the entire sampling design in Africa for the same species.

```
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
Ex2<-read.delim("Data_Group_project_2018_-_part_2_-_IMBRSea.txt", header=TRUE)
Ex2$Patch.f = factor(Ex2$Patch)
Ex2$continent.f = factor(Ex2$continent)
Ex2$mountain.f = factor(Ex2$mountain)
Ex2$altitude.f = factor(Ex2$altitude)
mixEx<- lmer(length~altitude+sex+sex:altitude+(1|Patch.f:altitude.f:mountain.f)+(1|mountain.f)+ (1|continent.f), data=Ex2)
anova(mixEx,ddf="Satterthwaite",type=3)
summary(mixEx)
```

I want to generate a plot with the "final" regression line that shows the increase of wing length with altitude taking into consideration the random effects. Can this be done on R i can't seem to find a way to do it.